# Connecting a GPS/GLONASS U-blox7 via USB gives “Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0)”

Tags: interface, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a [U-blox 7](https://www.u-blox.com/en/product/neo-7-series) but i am getting the message `Could not grab port (tty/ttyACM0)`

It should print something like this:

```
grep -m1 '$GPGLL' /dev/ttyACM0
```

*$GPGLL,4913.83009,N,01331.02537,E,181115.00,A,A*6A*

So far I've created the file to modify the kernel `49-ublox.rules`

[image: 49-ublox.rules]

which contains the following:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a7", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a7", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a7", MODE:="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a7", MODE:="0666"
```

But still I am not able to establish the communication.

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` output

[image: tail -f /var/log/syslog output]

Comment: Add the user(s) of that application to the "dialout" group.

Comment: id -Gn yourUserName # this prints out what groups you are member of.